# Issue when installing Kendo.MVC in WEB API Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue when I am installing the Kendo.MVC.UI dll into my project. I am installing the latest stable 2016.2.607 and my framework is 4.7.2

When I have started, it throws the following exception:

```
unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org',
```

and then I've installed the dll by the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions -Version 1.0.0-rc1-final
```

but now when i am instaling `kendo.MVC` , it is giving me the following exception:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc1-final' is not compatible with 'Kendo.Mvc 2016.2.607 constraint: Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0-rc2-20221)'.
```

Any help?

[image]

Comment: Just curious - do you have a specific need for a 2016 version of Kendo? Can you not use the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by installing the Kendo.MVC preview version by the following command:

```
Install-Package Kendo.Mvc -Version 2016.2.630-Preview
```